# xml Spring config using values from properties files

Tags: java, xml, spring, dependency-injection, properties

For DI in xml via setters using values from properties files I can use:

```
<beans>
..
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="props.properties"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="first" class="..">
        <property name="name" value="${values.name}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

But `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class is deprecated.

I have tried to use

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:props.properties"/>
```

instead of It but It didn't work

`prop.properties` in situated in `resources`, error message is `no declaration can be found for element 'context:property-placeholder'`

Comment: posted the answer below, let us know if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Javadocs of **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**

> as of 5.2; use
>   org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
>   instead which is more flexible through taking advantage of the
>   **Environment** and **PropertySource** mechanism

you can load property like below, you have to include **namespace  & schemalocation** in your beans tags. copy the beans tag from below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">


 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties,classpath:bar.properties"/>

    </bean>

</beans>
```